# Please advise my the stored procedure which is group by and total which different criteria

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have answered one of the interview questions as below.

There are two tables (employee and Department).
Show report No. of people(count) and total salary where IT Dept. salary from 250 to 500 and Sales Dept. salary from 250 to 1000 and Marketing Dept. salary from 250 to 1500.

Sample expected result below

```
Marketing               0      0.00
Information Technology  1      250.00
Sales                   2      1200.00
```

Employee table

```
EmpID   EmpName DeptID  Salary
1   Mike    1   1000.00
2   Paul    1   1500.00
3   John    1   2000.00
4   Joe     2   500.00
5   Kim     3   2000.00
6   Lim     3   2500.00
7   Sam     2   700.00
8   Mario   1   250.00
```

Department table

```
DeptID  DeptCode    DeptName
1   IT  Information Technology
2   ST  Sales
3   MT  Marketing
```

My Answer:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TheseAndThat]
    
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT dd.DeptName, ISNULL(TT.c,0) AS StaffCount , ISNULL(TT.s,0) AS TotalSalary  FROM [dbo].[Department] dd
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT d.DeptCode AS dcode, COUNT(*) as c, SUM(e.Salary) as s  FROM [dbo].[Employee] e
    JOIN [dbo].[Department] d
    ON e.DeptID = d.DeptID
    WHERE e.Salary between 250 and 500 AND d.DeptID = 1
    GROUP BY e.DeptID, d.DeptCode

    UNION 

    SELECT d.DeptCode AS dcode, COUNT(*) as c, SUM(e.Salary) as s  FROM [dbo].[Employee] e
    JOIN [dbo].[Department] d
    ON e.DeptID = d.DeptID
    WHERE e.Salary between 250 and 1000 AND d.DeptID = 2
    GROUP BY e.DeptID, d.DeptCode

    UNION 

    SELECT d.DeptCode AS dcode, COUNT(*) as c, SUM(e.Salary) as s  FROM [dbo].[Employee] e
    JOIN [dbo].[Department] d
    ON e.DeptID = d.DeptID
    WHERE e.Salary between 250 and 1500 AND d.DeptID = 3
    GROUP BY e.DeptID, d.DeptCode
    ) TT
    ON dd.DeptCode = TT.dcode
    ORDER BY TT.c 
END
```

I'm not sure my answer is correct. However, the result seems to be ok.
Please advise.

Comment: This is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Comment on the OP solution: Overall not an unreasonable attempt but you should have used `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` as you want all results included (See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql) Also why do you join to `[Department]` table in your sub-queries, when you do not retrieve any information from that table?

Comment: Hi @HoneyBadger, Thanks for your suggestion. I should post it codereview for next such similar questions.

Comment: Hi @Alex, Thanks your your highlight. Every question you asked is a new lesson I learn as I am quite new to SQL Querying.

Comment: @Mike, you are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was you I will go this this query (only 1 time scan to employee table)

```
SELECT d.DeptName, ISNULL(e.NoEmp,0) AS NoEmp, ISNULL(SumSalary,0) AS SumSalary
    FROM [dbo].[Department] AS d
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DeptID, COUNT(EmpID) As NoEmp, SUM (Salary) AS SumSalary
        FROM [dbo].[Employee]
        WHERE Salary BETWEEN 250 AND CASE WHEN DeptID = 1 THEN 500
                                          WHEN DeptID = 2 THEN 1000
                                          WHEN DeptID = 3 THEN 1500
                                     END

        GROUP BY DeptID) AS e ON d.DeptID = e.DeptID
    WHERE d.DeptID IN(1,2,3)
```

Comment: Thanks @Edward N for your answer. I have learnt many things from your query as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, the code to setup temp tables:

```
declare @employees table
(
    EmpID int,
    EmpName varchar(100),
    DeptID int,
    Salary decimal
)

declare @departament table
(
    DeptID int,
    DeptCode char(2),
    DeptName varchar(100)
)

insert into @employees values (1,'Mike',1,1000.00)
insert into @employees values (2,'Paul',1,1500.00)
insert into @employees values (3,'John',1,2000.00)
insert into @employees values (4,'Joe',2,500.00)
insert into @employees values (5,'Kim',3,2000.00)
insert into @employees values (6,'Lim',3,2500.00)
insert into @employees values (7,'Sam',2,700.00)
insert into @employees values (8,'Mario',1,250.00)

insert into @departament values (1, 'IT', 'Information Technology')
insert into @departament values (2, 'ST', 'Sales')
insert into @departament values (3, 'MT', 'Marketing')
```

Now, the report:

```
select DeptName, COALESCE(d2.DeptID, 0), COALESCE(Salaries,0) from @departament d2
left join 
(
    select COUNT(*) as DeptID, SUM(Salary) as Salaries from @departament d
    inner join @employees e on d.DeptID = e.DeptID
    where
        (d.DeptID = 1 and e.Salary between 250 and 500)
        or
        (d.DeptID = 2 and e.Salary between 250 and 1000)
        or
        (d.DeptID = 3 and e.Salary between 250 and 1500)
    group by d.DeptID) as sums on sums.DeptID = d2.DeptID
```

Comment: Thank you @Gustavo F for your answer. I have learnt many things from your query.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (uses the same temp tables as @GustavoF answer):

```
DECLARE @Input TABLE( DeptID INT, SalaryRangeMin decimal, SalaryRangeMax decimal )
INSERT INTO @Input
VALUES
( 1, 250, 500),
( 2 ,250 ,1000 ),
( 3 ,250 , 1500 )

SELECT D.DeptName, COUNT(EmpID) as EmployeeCount, ISNULL( SUM( e.Salary ), 0.0 ) as TotalSalary
FROM @Input AS I
   INNER JOIN @departament AS D ON I.DeptID = D.DeptID
   LEFT JOIN @Employees AS E ON I.DeptID = E.DeptID AND E.Salary BETWEEN I.SalaryRangeMin AND I.SalaryRangeMax
GROUP BY E.DeptID, D.DeptCode, D.DeptName
ORDER BY TotalSalary ASC
```

Output:

```
DeptName                    EmployeeCount TotalSalary
--------------------------- ------------- -------------
Marketing                   0             0
Information Technology      1             250
Sales                       2             1200
```

Comment: Thank you @Alex for your answer. I have learnt many things from your query.